# If f has closed graph and is bounded, f is continuous and the domain is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ has Euclidean distance, $\emptyset \neq S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and function $f:S \to \mathbb{R}^m$.

I want to prove this.

If graph of $f$ (i.e. $\{(x,f(x)) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+m} \mid x \in S \}$) is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ and $f$ is bounded, then $S$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f$ is continuous.

Could anyone give me some ideas ?

I proved that if $f$ is continuous and $S$ is closed, then graph of $f$ is closed, but I do not have ideas about the converse proposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be the graph of $f$. If $S$ is not closed, let $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a sequence in $S$ converging to some point $x\in\Bbb R^n\setminus S$. The sequence $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is bounded in $\Bbb R^m$, so it has a convergent subsequence, and without loss of generality we may assume that it actually converges, say to $y$. Then $\big\langle\langle x_n,f(x_n)\rangle:n\in\Bbb N\big\rangle$ in $G$ of $f$ converges to $\langle x,y\rangle$, and since $G$ is closed, $\langle x,y\rangle\in G$, and therefore $x\in S$. This contradiction shows that $S$ must be closed.

Now let $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a convergent sequence in $S$ with limit $x\in S$. We’d like to show that $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $f(x)$, as that would show that $f$ is continuous. As a first step we’ll show that $\sigma$ has a subsequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that $\langle f(x_{n_k}):k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $f(x)$.

The sequence $\big\langle\langle x_n,f(x_n)\rangle:n\in\Bbb N\big\rangle$ in $G$ is bounded, so it has a convergent subsequence $\big\langle\langle x_{n_k},f(x_{n_k})\rangle:k\in\Bbb N\big\rangle$, and since $G$ is closed, this subsequence must converge to some $\langle x,y\rangle\in G$. Then $y=f(x)$, since $\langle x,y\rangle\in G$, so $\langle f(x_{n_k}):k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $f(x)$. This shows that every sequence in $S$ converging to $x$ has a subsequence whose image under $f$ converges to $f(x)$.

If $\sigma$ does not converge to $f(x)$, there are an open nbhd $U$ of $f(x)$ and a subsequence $\langle f(x_{m_k}):k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of $\sigma$ such that $f(x_{m_k})\notin U$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$. But then $\langle x_{m_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence in $S$ converging to $x$ that cannot have a subsequence whose image under $f$ converges to $f(x)$, which is impossible. Thus, $\sigma$ converges to $f(x)$, and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your trying. Could you explain the details about "it has a convergent subsequence, and without loss of generality we may assume that it actually converges" ?

Comment: @mikecat: $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has a convergent subsequence $\langle f(x_{n_k}):k\in\Bbb N\rangle$. Just replace $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ by its subsequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and start with it instead: it also converges to $x$, so nothing important has changed. This is a very standard thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. I had a misunderstanding, also I understand it !

Comment: @mikecat: You’re welcome, and I’m delighted that you understand it.